# Matching pairs for character bound to a keystroke

Tags: auctex

I am using `smartparens` with AucTeX and it works great. I wanted to map a keystroke for the dollar sign, so I did it as follows -

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "s-m") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "$")))
```

But if I enter a dollar sign using the above keystroke, I no longer get a matching dollar sign as opposed to if enter a dollar sign the normal way (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>).

I'm not sure I understand why this happens. If anyone could point to the right place in the documentation so I can work out a fix, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Drew You are correct. It is bound to `(TeX-insert-dollar &optional ARG)` that takes an optional argument. I think I can just bind my keystroke to this function and it should work. Thanks!

Comment: @Drew  I did add the answer but I can only accept it in 2 days. I'll make sure to do so then. Okay I have removed the tag `smartparens`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the dollar-sign key was bound to command `TeX-insert-dollar`, which can take an optional argument indicating the number of dollar signs to print.

This is why mapping the same key to inserting the character `$` did not work.

To make it work, I just bound the key to a command that invokes `TeX-insert-dollar`, passing `2` as the argument, and all works fine.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "s-m")  
                (lambda () 
                        (interactive) 
                        (TeX-insert-dollar 2) 
                        (backward-char 1)))
```

Comment: @Drew is it fine now ?